# Redirect rule in Apache Server for two different servers

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, aem

I've two different servers - Server A and Server B.

Server A has a application **abc.example.com**

Server B has a application **www.example.com**

My need is to redirect **abc.example.com** to **www.example.com/abc**

I have assigned CNAME (Canonical Name) to **abc.example.com** as **www.example.com**, so currently whenever I hit **abc.example.com** it opens the content of **www.example.com** although it is not redirected yet.

What Redirect Rule I need to define in Apache server of 'Server B' so that request coming from **abc.example.com** from 'Server A' is redirected to **www.example.com/abc** including the path '/abc'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName abc.example.com

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/abc

</VirtualHost>
```